# how to set the interval of points on Y - Axis highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts for the first time, and I am trying to figure out how to set the Y axis points static.I would like to know how to set y-axis values as -0.0000000001,0.00000000,0.0000000001 and so on in Highcharts.
I have used min=-0.0000000005 and max=0.0000000005 , and the points on y axis come up as 0,0.0000,0.0000... Wherein I want it as -0.0000000001,0.00000000,0.0000000001

Answer (score 0):

You can use [label formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter) and [Highcharts numberFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Highcharts.numberFormat) then return correct values.